# PyCharms: Project Tool Window, Project structure, folder names in square braces

Tags: pycharm, project-structure

When I started using PyCharms, the first directory for the project was 6.1_Neeraj, which is marked in red rectangle in the picture. Later I copied the contents to the new directory 1.1. However, in the project directory structure, 6.1_Neeraj is still visible.

I need help for two things:

1. To get rid of the older directory
2. Explanation of why this could happen

Additional information:
I am using PyCharms by accessing its .sh file from decompressed tar.gz
Operating system: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

[image: In the red rectangle, the original directory name can be observed]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `Shift+F6` when project is selected and choose `Rename project`.

Comment: FYI: The project name is inferred from the directory name when project is created and then stored in the `.idea` directory. That's why it's not changed when you move the project to a different location.